# Moving from laravel 5.8 to 7x errors with maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I try to move my  laravel 5.8 to 7x branch.
I try to move 6 branch firstly.
But I got errors with maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar, as I got error
with

```
"maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "^1.3",
```

defined

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.5
    ...
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.2
    - Installation request for maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar ^1.3 -> satisfiable by maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar[v1.3.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
    - maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar v1.3.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[6.x-dev].
    - illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[6.x-dev].
```

I check here https://packagist.org/packages/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar:
and see that v1.3.0 is latest

my composer.json is :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "alaouy/youtube": "^2.2",
        "aloha/twilio": "^4.0",
        "arrilot/laravel-widgets": "^3.12",
        "cornford/googlmapper": "2.*",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^6.0",
        "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "5.x",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
        "elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.7",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^3.0",
        "jrean/laravel-user-verification": "^8.0",
        "laravel/cashier": "^10.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelium/sitemap": "^3.1",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "^1.3",
        "mews/captcha": "^2.2",
        "mews/purifier": "^2.1",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
        "pelago/emogrifier": "3.1.0",
        "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": ">2.2.0",
        "s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver": "~2.0",
        "snowfire/beautymail": "dev-master",
        "socialiteproviders/instagram": "^3.0",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.27",
        "spatie/db-dumper": "^2.14",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.1",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.1",
        "spatie/laravel-feed": "^2.1",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.4",
        "spatie/laravel-newsletter": "^4.2",
        "spatie/laravel-sitemap": "^5.3",
        "spatie/laravel-tags": "^2.1",
        "spipu/html2pdf": "^5.2",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.2",
        "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^1.2",
        "themsaid/laravel-mail-preview": "^2.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "^1.9",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1",
        "willvincent/feeds": "1.1.*",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.0.0",
        "zendframework/zend-diactoros": "^2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^2.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
        "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ],


        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan vendor:publish --provider=\"Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\JsValidationServiceProvider\" --tag=public --force"
        ]

    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Which steps have I to make to fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar` dependency need the version `5` of [`illuminate/support`](https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar/blob/master/composer.json#L13).

So you can't update `laravel` with this dependency. Moreover, it seems that this project was not updated since 3 years

But a fork exist [here](https://github.com/nelkasovic/laravel-full-calendar).And it works with `laravel` for 5,6 and 7 https://github.com/nelkasovic/laravel-full-calendar/blob/master/composer.json#L15

Comment: Thanks, looks like it will work with laravel 7 too?